# Visualizing communication pattern of MPI processes

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

Is there a tool that visualizes the communication pattern of processes in my my open-mpi code?
If not, i would like to write one.
Where do i start?

Comment: Intel Trace Analyzer and Collector

Comment: @arunmoezhi ITAC does not officially support tracing of applications built with Open MPI.

Comment: But I have used it to see the communication patterns among threads in a single node at least.

Answer (score 3):

There are some, examples:

- [Scalasca](http://scalasca.org/)
- [Paraver](http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/performance-tools/paraver)
- [Vampir](http://www.vampir.eu/)

Have a look at the [VI-HPS](http://www.vi-hps.org/tools/) stuff for more.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Vampir is a commercial tool and that Scalasca presents the result of a higher-level event analysis and is not actually able to visualise traces but launches external tools like Vampir and Paraver for that purpose.

Comment: How about if i add hooks to my MPI calls to log sender-receiver and message size information? Will it adversely degrade the performance?

Comment: @hrs that's basically what the other tools also do. See the PMPI interfaces provided by MPI: http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=perftools#PMPI

Comment: @haraldkl That's a great suggestion. I'll use it. Thanks.